# How to catch an exception message in python?

Tags: python, exception, try-catch

I want something of the form

```
try:
  # code
except *, error_message:
  print(error_message)
```

i.e I want to have a generic except block that catches all types of exceptions and prints an error message. Eg. "ZeroDivisionError: division by zero". Is it possible in python?

If I do the following I can catch all exceptions, but I won't get the error message.

```
try:
  # code
except:
  print("Exception occurred")
```

Comment: Did you try reading the documentation on exceptions? It's definitely in there

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try this:

```
except Exception as e:
    print(str(e))
```

Answer (score 5):

This will allow you to retrieve the message of any exception derived from the `Exception` base class:

```
try:
    raise Exception('An error has occurred.')
except Exception as ex:
    print(str(ex))
```

Comment: `AttributeError: 'KeyError' object has no attribute 'message'`

Comment: @bart-kosmala Sorry, this used to work in Python 2.x but doesn't work anymore for Python 3.x. I've updated my answer, please take back the downvote.